# select the last radio button of the group

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have several groups of radiobuttons in a form but I wonder if the latter is selected radiobutton in a specific group, I tried this:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {

if ($('input[name$="cats"]:last', this).is(':checked')) {

            alert ('the last button');
            return false;

}

});
```

It does not work... I hope your help, thank you and sorry for my english xd

**EDIT...**

strange, I have no error in the error console or firebug.

My form is broad, but this is an example:

```
<form id="myform" action="">

<fieldset class="left">
<legend>My Dogs</legend>                        
<p><input name="dogs" type="radio" value="Doberman" class="radio" /> Bobby</p>
<p><input name="dogs" type="radio" value="German Shepherd" /> Drake</p>
<p><input name="dogs" type="radio" value="schnauzer" /> Bunchie</p>
<p><input name="dogs" type="radio" value="Others" /> Other</p>
<p><input name="otherdog" id="otherdog" type="text" class="text" /></p>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="right">
<legend>My Cats</legend>
<p><input name="cats" type="radio" value="Balinese" /> Kitty</p>
<p><input name="cats" type="radio" value="Bengal" /> Chucky</p>
<p><input name="cats" type="radio" value="Chausie" /> Gordon</p>
<p><input name="cats" type="radio" value="Others" /> Other</p>
<p><input name="othercat" id="othercat" type="text" class="text" /></p>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

And my JS is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#myform').submit(function() {

if ($(this).find('input[name$="dogs"]:checked').length == 0) {
            alert('Select dogs.');
            return false;
        }

        if ($('input[name$="dogs"]:last', this).is(':checked')) {

            alert ('this is the last');
            return false;
        }

});

if ($(this).find('input[name$="cats"]:checked').length == 0) {
            alert('Select cats.');
            return false;
        }

        if ($('input[name$="cats"]:last', this).is(':checked')) {

            alert ('this is the last');
            return false;
        }

alert('all good :)');
        return false;

});

});
```

the only thing that happens is that you do not enter the condition:

*" if ($('input[name$="cats"]:last', this).is(':checked')) { "*

Comment: do you get any javascript error ? you could see javascript errors if you have installed a developing tool such as firebug for firefox (press F12 to bring the tool window and activate it then refresh the page and see if there is error)

Answer (score 4):

[Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/tpn5c/1/), am I missing something here?

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
   if ($('input[name$="cats"]:last', this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('the last button');
        return false;
   }
});

<form id="myform">
    <input type="radio" name="foocats"/>
    <input type="radio" name="foocats"/>
    <input type="radio" name="foocats" checked="checked"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You're finding the checked button, which is not necessarily the last button.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting?

i recreated this and it seems to work [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/hDgCY/2/)

Comment: im not sure what really you want but i see from the javascript that you should get a syntax error you have an extra });